# is it possible for aws dns private and public for same domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain called "foo.com" that is currently managed by GoDaddy. Within my AWS Virtual Private Cloud (VPC), I have two services: db.foo.com and api.foo.com.

I want to set up a private zone in Amazon Route 53 that only includes these two entries:

- db.foo.com --> 10.0.1.201
- api.foo.com --> 10.0.1.202

However, entries like [www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com) and app.foo.com do not reside in AWS. My question is whether I need to add these entries to the private host DNS for the VPC in addition to the GoDaddy DNS. Alternatively, can Route 53 be configured with DNS resolver rules to check the private DNS first and then forward the query to the "default" DNS if the entry is not found?

So the lookup follow for [www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com) ideally would be:

- lookup [www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com) in route53 private dns => NOT FOUND
- forward to godaddy dns or the true "SOA" for foo.com

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. It's called [Split-view DNS](https://tutorialsdojo.com/split-view-dns-using-amazon-route-53/). A public and private DNS with the same name. I've done this before in R53, not sure if it will work if the public domain is in another provider. But I think it will. And you don't need extra configuration.

Checkout this [Split-view DNS](https://tutorialsdojo.com/split-view-dns-using-amazon-route-53/) for explanation and example.

Comment: thanks!  i read about that too after posting.  it seems like you still need to maintain two hosted zones, one public and one private.  that's fine.  it means every time i update the private zone, i need to also update the public zone too.  there is a possibility of using resolver rules, but haven't vetted it out completely.  i was hoping it can magically merge the two zones through hops - not found in internal dns, forward to external dns.  but it's also the same domain -  not subdomain - so not sure if it's possible.